# Passing Seq[T] as a vararg in Scala

Tags: scala, sequence, variadic-functions

This code won't compile

```
val sortedSet = SortedSet[Int](Array(1,2,3,4).toSeq)

  Error: type mismatch; found  :Seq[Int] required Int
```

However, here is the definition of apply in SortedSet:

```
def apply[A](elems: A*)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): CC[A] = (newBuilder[A](ord) ++= elems).result
```

It says that elem is a vararg and therefore in should be of type Seq[A]
What am I missing? Why I can't pass Seq as vararg?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `: _*`

```
scala> SortedSet[Int](Array(1,2,3,4).toSeq: _*)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 4)
```